# asp.net c# linq search List<object> tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an object with child objects, that I need to search for a specific ID in one of the child objects.

The object tree is like:

```
Sites (id, name)
->Zones[] (id, name)
-->Placements[] (id, name)
```

I have it stored in a `List<Sites>` with multiple sites, each of which can `have multiple zones, and multiple placements`.

I'm trying to search for **two things:**

1. The Placements[].id = placement ID
2. The Zones[].id = zone ID

Each search result object should also contain the parent's information, so I can refer to that as well.

I'm trying:

```
        List<SitesList> sitesTree = getSites();
        var searchresults = sitesTree.Find(zones => zones.zones[0].id == zoneId);
        if(searchresults != null)
        {                
            details.siteName = searchresults.name;
            details.siteId = searchresults.id;
            details.zoneName = searchresults.zones[0].name;
            details.zoneId = searchresults.zones[0].id;
        }
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

Comment: check that `zones` is not empty before accessing `zones[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `SelectMany` to flatten your data structure and select that in to an anonymous type.  That would give you the parent site and zone on the object so you can work with them, for example:

```
var results = sites.SelectMany(s => s.Zones.Select(z => new {ParentSite = s, Zone = z}))
                               .SelectMany(x => x.Zone.Placements.Select(p => new {ParentSite = x.ParentSite,
                                                                                  ParentZone = x.Zone,
                                                                                  Placement = p}))
                              .Where(x => x.Placement.Id == 2 && x.ParentZone.Id == zoneId)
                              .ToList();
```

Then the resultant anonymous structure will look like:

```
{ParentSite: Site, ParentZone: Zone, Placement: Placement}
```

So you can refer to the placement from the `Placement` property, the parent zone from the `ParentZone` property and the parent site from the `ParentSite` property.

Answer (score 0):

You are also only checking that the first zone in the array of zones has the id set to zoneid. Is it your intention to only search the first child? Tf not use:

```
var searchresults = sitesTree.Find(zones => zones.zones.Any(z=>z.id == zoneId));
```

That will find any entries in the sitesTree list that have at least one child with the zone id.